# Intelliji idea to eclipse migration. Where to find same settings for IntelliJ IDEA's "Web Resource Directory Path Dialog" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

I have j2ee web project in IntelliJ IDEA with complex web resource directory structure

[image]

Where to find the equivalent of this setting in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you have Java EE development portion of Eclipse installed. The easiest way is to download "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" packages from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads. Next, make sure that you've created a "Dynamic Web Project". Finally, go to Project Properties -> Deployment Assembly.

If you don't see Deployment Assembly page, you are using an old version of Eclipse. There is a way to do this in the older versions, but you will be happier if you upgrade to the newest release. See link above.

Comment: thanks, it's actually what I need Small addition: this settings stored in ${workspace}\.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component